# How to specify which tag to return in Java via SOAPUI Testrunner getRunContext

Tags: java, xpath, soapui, test-runner

I'm currently using the following generic method to access individual xml tags within a SOAPUI response:

```
public class SoapUIAPI {
private String soapUITestCase;
private String tagValue;
private TestRunner runner;

public String getWebServiceResponseTagValue (String tag){
    tagValue = runner.getRunContext().expand("${"+soapUITestCase+"#Response#//*:"+tag+"}");
    return tagValue;
}
```

`runner.getRunContext().expand` almost seems to be taking xpath expressions (but not quite?) my problem is I have an xml response that looks something like this:

```
<content>
  <memNum>123456</memNum>
  <displayName>Mr John Smith</displayName>
  <prefName>John</prefName>
  <dob>11/09/1948</dob>
  <occDesc>Truck Driver</occDesc>
  <IRDNumber>19-211-314</IRDNumber>
  <contactDetails>
     <contact>
        <MEMBER_PHONE_ID>123456</MEMBER_PHONE_ID>
        <contactType>Mobile 2</contactType>
        <countryCode>(+64)</countryCode>
        <std>021</std>
        <number>54545454</number>
     </contact>
     <contact>
        <MEMBER_PHONE_ID>34567</MEMBER_PHONE_ID>
        <contactType>Business Phone</contactType>
        <countryCode>(+36)</countryCode>
        <std>04</std>
        <number>8756845</number>
        <ext/>
     </contact>
     <contact>
        <MEMBER_PHONE_ID>45678</MEMBER_PHONE_ID>
        <contactType>Preferred Email 1</contactType>
        <email>Test@gmail.com</email>
     </contact>
     <contact>
        <MEMBER_PHONE_ID>56789</MEMBER_PHONE_ID>
        <contactType>Preferred Email 2</contactType>
        <email>test@test.com</email>
     </contact>
  </contactDetails>
  <branch>New York</branch>
  <adviser>Warren Duck</adviser>
</content>
```

How can I specify which `<email>` tag to return, while still using `runner.getRunContext().expand`?

Maybe others will disagree but I find the SOAPUI API documentation to be lacking.

Comment: In this case, you need to specify any other field value as reference to retrieve the specific email. For eg: `retrieve email where member phone id is 45678` or `where std is 021` etc.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to have the right `xpath` to retrieve the required value.

Since there is a list of contacts available, it requires reference of another relative element to be able to get the right email.

For eg:
 - Using *member phone id*: to retrieve email of a contact where `MEMBER_PHONE_ID` is *56789*, xpath would look like:
`//MEMBER_PHONE_ID[contains(text(),'56789')]/following-sibling::email/text()`

So, you would need to pass additional information to get the specific email.

Such as `relativeTag` (MEMBER_PHONE_ID), `relativeTagValue`(56789) apart from existing `tag`

```
String value = "${"+soapUITestCase+"#Response#//" + relativeTag + "[contains(text(),'" + relativeTagValue+"')]/following-sibling::" + tag + "/text()}";
```

The output of `value` would be (assuming value of `soapUITestCase` is *Test1*):

```
${Test1#Response#//MEMBER_PHONE_ID[contains(text(),'56789')]/following-sibling::tag/text()}
```

Then you call pass that `value` to expand method.

```
tagValue = runner.getRunContext().expand(value);
```

Note that you need to handle if there are any namespaces involved in the response, there aren't any *namcespaces* in the current response provided.

Comment: Thanks @Rao I should've just tried, I assumed it wasn't xPath as `//*:email ` doesn't appear to me to be valid xPath (but works). Your solution works perfectly.

Comment: @AutomationTester, glad to know that it is helpful.